# How do I incorporate a loop into a bash alias

Tags: bash, for-loop, alias

I'm trying to create an alias that loops through a few folders and runs a build command but I keep getting an output that just displays `for >`.

This is a function that I have in my .zshrc file

```
recurse_build () {
    for src in `ls`; do 
        cd $src; build; cd ..
    done
}
```

And I'm trying to make an alias

```
alias br='recurse_build'
```

but I end up with the following prompt

```
for >
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: fixed syntax error in function. Was a bad case typing instead of copy pasting

Comment: Why don't you just use a function instead of an alias? Btw you have a syntax error in the function.

Comment: Why would you define a function and map it to an alias? Use the function all directly

Comment: Your function definition is broken (as currently posted); analyze it at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Comment: @Inian, I didn't think to just run the function and so I aliased. works when I run the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from the missing backquote on your command substitution, this is the wrong way to iterate over files anyway. Use a glob pattern.

```
recurse_build () {
    for src in */; do
        pushd "$src" || continue   # Don't do anything if pushd fails
        build
        popd
    done
}
```

Using `pushd` and `popd` is a little cleaner than having to remember where to return to.

Comment: Fixed the missing backquote, and I didn't know about this way to iterate over files in bash. I did just try the syntax you suggested but I still get the `for > ` prompt instead of actually having it do the build. Let me see if I can debug it a bit.  

Edit: rant he function directly and it seems to work. It doesn't work in the alias but I can deal with just calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the missing backtick on the right, but processing the output of
ls is usually a bad idea anyway. This works

```
recurse_build(){
    for src in */; do
        cd "$src" && ./build && cd ..
    done
}

#TEST 
mkdir -p a b c 
echo 'echo $PWD:$0' |tee a/build b/build c/build >/dev/null
chmod  +x a/build b/build c/build 


recurse_build
```